# Pandas concat() in Python 3.9 in a def returning the error: No objects to concatenate, while inline scripting there is no error

Tags: python, pandas, concatenation

Using Python 3.9 I have several pandas dataframes, each are stored within the `self.pointcloud.<dict>`.
This looks something like the following, named after their date of capture:

```
self.pointcloud['20180712']['data']
self.pointcloud['20180713']['data']
self.pointcloud['20180714']['data']
```

Each `['data']` dict is a pandas dataframe all containing the same columns.

I'm running into an issue then I try to concat them into a single dict.

I can easily get all the dataframes in a list:

```
def get_data(self, tag):
    return [self.pointcloud[pc]['data'] for pc in self.pointcloud if self.pointcloud[pc]['data']['tag'].unique() == [tag]]
```

This uses list comprehension, it filters the data based on the `tag` value relative to the `tag` column, but that's not an issue.

So now I have all the data I want to merge them into one single dataframe, if I run my code in debug mode the following gives me no issue and runs as expected:

```
tag = 'a value'
df_list = self.get_data(tag)
new_df = pd.concat(df_list)
```

However, when I add it to a def I get the error: `ValueError: No objects to concatenate`

```
def merge_pointclouds(self, tag):
    df_list = self.get_data(tag)
    return pd.concat(df_list)

self.merge_pointclouds('a value')
```

As I stated, in debug mode it works, even within the `merge_pointclouds` def, is there anything obvious that I'm missing?

The exact error from Pycharm:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2020.2.2\plugins\python-ce\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py", line 1448, in _exec
    pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals)  # execute the script
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2020.2.2\plugins\python-ce\helpers\pydev\_pydev_imps\_pydev_execfile.py", line 18, in execfile
    exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)
  File "C:/.../PycharmProjects/PCPro2023_0_3_2py39-64/pc.py", line 927, in <module>
    debug(debugging=debugging)
  File "C:/.../PycharmProjects/PCPro2023_0_3_2py39-64/pc.py", line 68, in debug
    pc.set_distance_between()
  File "C:/.../PycharmProjects/PCPro2023_0_3_2py39-64/pc.py", line 388, in set_distance_between
    data_top = self.merge_pointclouds(tag='Top')
  File "C:/.../PycharmProjects/PCPro2023_0_3_2py39-64/pc.py", line 221, in merge_pointclouds
    res = pd.concat(df_list)
  File "C:\...\PycharmProjects\PCPro2023_0_3_py39-64\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\util\_decorators.py", line 331, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\...\PycharmProjects\PCPro2023_0_3_py39-64\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\concat.py", line 368, in concat
    op = _Concatenator(
  File "C:\...\PycharmProjects\PCPro2023_0_3_py39-64\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\concat.py", line 425, in __init__
    raise ValueError("No objects to concatenate")
ValueError: No objects to concatenate
```

Comment: Have printed out the `df_list` and made sure that it's not empty?

Comment: @Plagon yes, I print(df_list) and two dataframes are printed. I'm using Pycharm, so in debug mode I can step into the code and I see there are two dataframes in the df_list[]. In debug the code runs without issue. It simply does not like `pd.concat(df_list)`. df_list is a list of pandas dataframes.

Comment: @Plagon To add, both dataframes have data in them and the columns are identical